# How does flutter's Text widget let it display all spaces that end with a space?

Tags: flutter

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.blue,
      border: Border.all(width: 1.0,color: Colors.red)
    ),
    child: Text('11111111               '),
  ),
```

When I look at the effect of this Container, all the spaces after 111... are not displayed, unless I add a non-space character at the end. How can I solve this?

Comment: it's displaying the spaces use this code to show  child: Text('11111111               ', style: new TextStyle(background: new Paint()..color = Colors.green),),

Comment: I need it to really take up space. If I display it in this way, when I put two identical Text('1111111          ') controls on one line, the 1111... of the following Text will occupy the front trailing space. This is not an ideal result

Comment: Have you tried if some of the other spaces available in unicode are retained? http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html

Comment: Spaces at the end seem to be rendered now.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like at the moment, **the trailing whitespaces can't be kept in any way**, since they are removed at a lower level, by the Flutter engine in C++, when calculating the line breaks.

A `Text` is actually a `RichText` which contains a `TextSpan`, itself rendered by a `ParagraphBuilder` belonging to `dart:ui` ([link here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/flutter/engine/+/refs/heads/master/lib/ui/text/paragraph_builder.cc)). And the thing is that when the paragraph is rendered, line breaks are calculated by a third party member of the Flutter engine, which remove every trailing spaces ([link here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/flutter/engine/+/master/third_party/txt/src/minikin/LineBreaker.cpp), see line 173).

I'd suggest to fill a new issue on Github to mention that.

Answer (score 5):

One workaround I found is to replace each regular space at the end of Text() with

```
String.fromCharCodes([
        // no-brake space
        0x00A0,
        // space
        0x0020
      ])
```

Your piece of code will look like this:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.blue,
      border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.red)),
      child: Text('11111111'.padRight(
        '               '.length,
        String.fromCharCodes([
          // no-brake space
          0x00A0,
          // space
          0x0020
          ])))),
```